# Spring WebClient cannot read data from REST API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, webclient

In my Spring Boot app, I want to read data from the following APIs using Spring WebClient as shown below (I have no prior experience and after making several search on many pages and articles, I concluded to use Spring WebClient):

The endpoint URLs are:

***service:***

```
private static final String BASE_URL = "https://demo-api/v1";
private WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(BASE_URL);

public Mono fetchMergedData(String city) {
    Mono<EduData> edu = getEduData(city);
    Mono<GeoData> geo = getGeoData(city);

    return Mono.zip(edu, geo, MergedData::new);
}

public Mono<EduData> getEduData(String city) {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri("/edu/{city}", city)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(EduData.class);
}

public Mono<GeoData> getGeoData(String city) {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri("/geo/{city}", city)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(GeoData.class);
}
```

Here are the models:

***models:***

```
@Getter
public class EduData {

    private int institution;
}

@Getter
public class GeoData {

    private int population;
}

@Getter
public class MergedData {

    private int institution;
    private int population;

    public MergedData(EduData edu, GeoData geo) {
        this.institution = edu.getInstitution();
        this.population = get.getPopulation();
    }
}
```

Although there is no error and all the endpoints return data when I test using Postman, I cannot see any data in neither `edu`, `geo` variables, nor the return of `fetchMergedData()` method. So, where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To get data out of a Mono, you can either `block()` (turning this into a blocking operation), or `subscribe()` and pass it a `Consumer` or `Subscriber`.

Simply blocking the call would give you the results, but if you want to do this in a reactive manner then you'll need to subscribe to the Mono.

```
// Using a block
this.institution = edu.getInstitution().block();

// Using a subscription, when available, EduData can be accessed via response.get
AtomicReference<EduData> response = new AtomicReference<>();
edu.getInstitution().subscribe(response::set);
```

Here's a simple subscription that provides a `Consumer`.

```
public class SomeClass {
  EduData eduData;

  public void setEduData(EduData eduData) {
    this.eduData = eduData;
  }

  public void fetchData(String city) {
    webClient.get()
        .uri("/edu/{city}", city)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(EduData.class).subscribe(this::setEduData);
  }
}
```

When the response is available, the `setEduData` method will be called with the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. But do I have to use atomic reference? Could you post an example from mono to Entity without blocking?

Comment: @Alfred see my edits